# unique solution to integral functional equation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, functional-equations

I have the following equation:

$f(x,y)=Pr(v\xi-y>max\{v-x,0\})$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $\forall x,y$ $ $ $ $ (1)

where $f(x,y)$ is a known function and $f(x,y) \in (0,1)$ , $v$ and $\xi$ are independent random variables with $v\sim F_v$ ($F_v$ is the CDF of $v$) and $\xi \sim F_\xi$ ($F_\xi$ is the CDF of $\xi$ with domain $[1,+\infty$) ). In the above equation (1) $F_v$ is known, whereas $F_\xi$ is unknown.

I want to understand whether there is a unique CDF $F_\xi$ solving equation (1)/ for which equation (1) holds.

How should my proof proceed? Is anyone familiar with similar cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should my proof proceed? Is anyone familiar with similar cases?

When working with probability problems, if you aren't sure how to proceed, a good question to ask is: what if my random variable is…

- …a normal distribution (this might be tricky, because the normal CDF has no elementary closed form),
- …a Cauchy distribution, or
- …a constant (a.s.)?

In your case, suppose $v=0$ a.s.  Then $$f(x,y)=\mathbb{P}[{0\cdot\xi-y>\max(v-x,0)}]=\mathbb{P}[-y>\max(v-x,0)]$$ which has no dependence on $\xi$.  Consequently it cannot determine $\xi$ uniquely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Let's assume $F_v$ and $F_\xi$ are both nondegenerate CDF. Does this help for understanding whether a unique solution exists for $F_\xi$?

Comment: @Dreamer93: "Does it help"? No, once you rule out the trivial examples, the problem gets harder !  Actually, I don't think $f$ ever determines $F_\xi$ uniquely.  Your problem calls this an "integral functional equation", but you haven't written any integrals; to proceed further, you should probably try to manipulate the probability expression to see if you can write down the integral in a nice form.

Comment: Note that this site frowns on asking questions without explaining what partial progress you've made; the (current) downvote on your question probably reflects that the original post doesn't appear to show much engagement with the problem.  Trying some algebraic manipulations and explaining why your "mathematical toolbox" doesn't seem to help could be missing context.